# Remove dynamically created textboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I am creating textboxes dynamically on button click. I want to know to remove textboxes with another button click.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table-fill tbfill">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th class="text-left" runat="server">Screen Name</th>
         <th class="text-left" runat="server">Seats Available</th>
         <th class="text-left"></th>
       </tr> 
    </thead>
   </table>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="ADD"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function ()
       {
        $("tbody.addScreen").append('<tr id="row0">' +
            '<td class="text-left" name="screenName"> <input id="screenNameTextBox"/> </td>' +
            '<td class="text-left"> <input id="seatsAvlTextBox" name="seatsAvl" /> </td>' +
            '<td class="text-left"> <input type="button" value="Remove" id=Removebtn/> </td>' +
            '</tr>');
       });
```

I have a Remove button here. When I click the button I need to remove the textboxes from the corresponding row. How can I do this?

Comment: You will have many items with the same ids `row0`, `Removebtn` which is incorrect. Use classes instead.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev:can you plz show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have many items with the same ids `Removebtn`, `row0`, `screenNameTextBox` etc. which is incorrect. Use classes instead.

Change

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" id=Removebtn/>
```

and other `id`s to similar classes:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="RemoveBtn"/>
```

Then, you will be able to use event delegation to assign a handler for all these buttons. For example, this code will remove the whole row on button click:

```
$(document).on('click', '.RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ha9pv3n3/1/).

If you want to remove textboxes only, then use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$('.tbfill').on('click', '#RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').remove();        
})
```

Use `$(this).closest('tr').remove()` if you want to remove complete row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only textboxes

```
$(document).on('click', '.RemoveBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input:text").remove();
});
```

Comment: It will remove button as well.